# .NET MAUI Layout in animated Frame

Tags: c#, grid, maui

I am trying to figure out how to display correctly the CollectionView elements in an animated Frame.

I show you some images to understand batter:
Starting position:
[image]
Here I would like to see only the top image. This is where the side bar is ,,closed,,. When I press the button I would like to see something like this:
[image]
As you can see I can see only 3 element is from the CollectionView , but there should be 19 element. The elements are not displayer correctly as shown. I am still learning the UI part, so any help are welcome.

This is what I do so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Solution.MobileApp.Converters"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Solution.MobileApp.ViewModels"
             xmlns:component="clr-namespace:Solution.MobileApp.Components"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Solution.MobileApp.Models"
             x:Class="Solution.MobileApp.Pages.Tabs.PlayerPage"
             x:DataType="viewModels:PlayerPageViewModel"
             Title="wPlayer"
             BackgroundColor="Black"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             Unloaded="OnUnloaded">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <toolkit:TimeSpanToSecondsConverter x:Key="TimeSpanConverter" />
        <converters:SecondsToStringConverter x:Key="SecondsToStringConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.Column="0"
               ZIndex="100"
               Padding="5,5,5,5"
               Margin="5,5,5,5"
               x:Name="trackListSideBar"
               HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ImageButton Source="song.png"
                             WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40"
                             Clicked="OnTrackListImageClicked"
                             VerticalOptions="Start"
                             HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Playlist}"
                                BackgroundColor="White"
                                VerticalOptions="Start"
                                HorizontalOptions="End">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="5"/>
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:TrackModel">
                            <component:TrackListItemComponent Track="{Binding .}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>

        <toolkit:MediaElement
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                x:Name="mediaElement"
                ShouldAutoPlay="True"
                Source="{Binding Source}"
                MediaEnded="OnMediaEnded"
                MediaFailed="OnMediaFailed"
                MediaOpened="OnMediaOpened"
                PositionChanged="OnPositionChanged"
                StateChanged="OnStateChanged"
                SeekCompleted="OnSeekCompleted" />

        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,0,0,15">
            <Label HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="Current State: {0}">
                        <Binding Path="CurrentState" Source="{x:Reference mediaElement}" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Label.Text>
            </Label>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,10,0,10" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*" ColumnSpacing="5">
            <ImageButton Grid.Column="0" Source="back.png" Clicked="OnPreviousClicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" />
            <ImageButton Grid.Column="1" Source="play.png" Clicked="OnPlayOrPauseClicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50">
                <ImageButton.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton"
                                     Binding="{Binding CurrentState, Source={x:Reference mediaElement}}"
                                     Value="Playing">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="pause.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton"
                                     Binding="{Binding CurrentState, Source={x:Reference mediaElement}}"
                                     Value="Paused">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="play.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton"
                                     Binding="{Binding CurrentState, Source={x:Reference mediaElement}}"
                                     Value="None">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="play.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ImageButton.Triggers>
            </ImageButton>
            <ImageButton Grid.Column="2" Source="stop.png" Clicked="OnStopClicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" />
            <ImageButton Grid.Column="3" Source="forward.png" Clicked="OnNextClicked" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" />
        </Grid>

        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,10,0,10">
            <Slider x:Name="positionSlider"
                        MinimumTrackColor="Gray"
                        DragStarted="OnSliderDragStarted"
                        DragCompleted="OnSliderDragCompleted"/>

            <HorizontalStackLayout Padding="0,10,0,10">
                <Label HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}Position: {0}/{1}">
                            <Binding Path="Position" Source="{x:Reference mediaElement}" Converter="{StaticResource SecondsToStringConverter}" />
                            <Binding Path="Duration" Source="{x:Reference mediaElement}" Converter="{StaticResource SecondsToStringConverter}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Label.Text>
                </Label>
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </VerticalStackLayout>

        <Grid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Padding="0,10,0,10" RowDefinitions="*,*" ColumnDefinitions="*,*" ColumnSpacing="5">
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="Volume:" />
                        <Span Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference mediaElement}, Path=Volume, StringFormat='{}{0:P0}'}" />
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
            <Slider Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                    Maximum="1.0"
                    Minimum="0.0"
                    MinimumTrackColor="Red"
                    MaximumTrackColor="Gray"
                    Margin="10,0,10,0">
                <Slider.Value>
                    <Binding Path="Volume" Source="{x:Reference mediaElement}" />
                </Slider.Value>
            </Slider>
            <ImageButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                             HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"
                             Source="mute.png"
                             Clicked="OnMuteClicked">
                <ImageButton.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton"
                                     Binding="{Binding ShouldMute, Source={x:Reference mediaElement}}"
                                     Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="sound.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton"
                                     Binding="{Binding ShouldMute, Source={x:Reference mediaElement}}"
                                     Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="mute.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ImageButton.Triggers>
            </ImageButton>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>

namespace Solution.MobileApp.Pages.Tabs;

public partial class PlayerPage : ContentPage
{
    public PlayerPageViewModel ViewModel => BindingContext as PlayerPageViewModel;

    private bool isSideBarOpen = false;

    public PlayerPage(PlayerPageViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;

        InitializeComponent();

        mediaElement.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnPreviousClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) => mediaElement.Source = ViewModel.PreviousTrack();

    private void OnNextClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) => mediaElement.Source = ViewModel.NextTrack();

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == MediaElement.DurationProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            positionSlider.Maximum = mediaElement.Duration.TotalSeconds;
        }
    }

    private void OnMediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    private void OnStateChanged(object sender, MediaStateChangedEventArgs e)
    { }

    private void OnMediaFailed(object sender, MediaFailedEventArgs e) => mediaElement.Source = ViewModel.PreviousTrack();

    private void OnMediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e) => mediaElement.Source = ViewModel.PreviousTrack();

    private void OnPositionChanged(object sender, MediaPositionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        positionSlider.Value = e.Position.TotalSeconds;
    }

    private void OnSeekCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    private void OnPlayOrPauseClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch(mediaElement.CurrentState)
        {
            case MediaElementState.None:
                mediaElement.Source = ViewModel.PlayTrack();
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Playing:
                mediaElement.Pause();
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Paused:
                mediaElement.Play();
                break;
            default:
                mediaElement.Stop();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnStopClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.Stop();
    }

    private void OnMuteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.ShouldMute = !mediaElement.ShouldMute;
    }

    private void OnUnloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop and cleanup MediaElement when we navigate away
        mediaElement.Handler?.DisconnectHandler();
    }

    private void OnSliderDragCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(sender);

        var newValue = ((Slider)sender).Value;
        mediaElement.SeekTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(newValue));
        mediaElement.Play();
    }

    private void OnSliderDragStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mediaElement.Pause();
    }

    private async void OnTrackListImageClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var from = isSideBarOpen ? DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width * 0.65 : 50;
        var to = !isSideBarOpen ? DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width * 0.65 : 50;

        await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            var animation = new Animation(x => trackListSideBar.WidthRequest = x, from, to);
            animation.Commit(this, "TrackListSideBarAnimation", 16, 500, Easing.Linear);
        });

        isSideBarOpen = !isSideBarOpen;
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Solution.MobileApp.Converters"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Solution.MobileApp.Models"
             x:Class="Solution.MobileApp.Components.TrackListItemComponent"
             x:Name="this">

    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <viewModel:TrackModel />
    </ContentView.BindingContext>

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <toolkit:TimeSpanToSecondsConverter x:Key="TimeSpanConverter" />
        <converters:SecondsToStringConverter x:Key="SecondsToStringConverter" />
    </ContentView.Resources>

    <SwipeView x:Name="swipe">
        <SwipeView.RightItems>
            <SwipeItems>
                <SwipeItem IconImageSource="delete.png"
                           BackgroundColor="Red"
                           Invoked="OnDelete" />
            </SwipeItems>
        </SwipeView.RightItems>
        <Frame BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"
               Margin="2"
               BackgroundColor="#101010"
               BorderColor="#101010">

            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapp"/>
            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="5*,1*">
                <Label Text="{Binding Track.Title}" TextColor="White" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Track.Length, Converter={StaticResource SecondsToStringConverter}}" 
                       TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="End"/>
                </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </SwipeView>

</ContentView>

public partial class TrackListItemComponent : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TrackProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Track), typeof(TrackModel), typeof(TrackListItemComponent), null);

    public TrackModel Track
    {
        get => (TrackModel)GetValue(TrackProperty);
        set => SetValue(TrackProperty, value);
    }

    public TrackListItemComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }

    private void OnTapp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { }
}
```

Comment: if your CollectionView is contained in a StackLayout, you need to specify a height.  Or use a different container

Comment: What's the `PlayerPageViewModel `, `TrackModel ` and `TimeSpanToSecondsConverter `? Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver so that we can test on our side?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1__b2-muuGI_9I9z8G4YEh5A01N0OnRnq/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Your file is too large, and our computer is restricted from downloading due to permission restrictions. You can try to remove the bin and obj folders of your demo and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CollectionView` is inside a `Frame` whose the `HeightRequest` is equal to **50**. This is probably why you wouldn't see anything else than the first elements in your collection.

Also, you can find from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling?view=net-maui-8.0) that:

> Placing a CollectionView inside a VerticalStackLayout can stop the
> CollectionView scrolling, and can limit the number of items that are
> displayed. In this situation, replace the VerticalStackLayout with a Grid.

If you are interested, I provided walkthrough example [here](https://www.mauicestclair.fr/en/posts/tutos/my-first-app/6-arrange-elements-on-a-page) that will help you arranging elements in a .NET MAUI page using the Grid component.